# Difference between values and how the code reads the values in CS50

Tags: cs50, string-comparison

Here's my main code:

```
// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name, int candidatecount, candidate candidates1[MAX])
{
    // TODO
    for (int a = 0; a < candidatecount; a++)
    {
        if (candidatecount == a)
        {
            printf("a\n");
            return false;
        }
        if (name == candidates1[a].names)
        {
            printf("b\n");
            candidates[a].votes = candidates[a].votes + 1;
        }
        printf("%s, %s\n", candidates1[a].names, name);
    }
    printf("1\n");
    return(name);
}
```

This was my command line:

```
    ./plurality R D
```

The output (with my responses) was this:

```
    Number of voters: 3
    Vote: R
    R, R
    D, R
    1
    Vote: D
    R, D
    D, D
    1
    Vote: R
    R, R
    D, R
    1
    vote candidate 0 go around 0
    b 0 e (null)
    vote candidate 0 go around 1
    b 0 e (null)
    (null) won with 0 votes.
```

It makes it seem like this:

```
    if (name == candidates1[a].names)
```

should work, but it doesn't, because the printf I have after it doesn't work.
Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review the [Week 3 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gR6nycuZKlM), starting around the 40 minute mark. The prof says

> It turns out that in C, you can't use equals equals to compare two strings.

He introduces [`strcmp`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) at that time, and will give further explanation about why in the next lesson. The simple explanation is that strings are pointers and `==` will compare the *addresses* of the operands, not the *values*.